# Average Quantity with subselect

Tags: sql

I have following table, where OrderID is unique and ordernumber is not unique:

```
OrderID|Ordernumber|ProductID|Quantity
1|1234|10|12|
2|1234|55|10|
3|1234|55|22|
4|1029|99|44|
```

1.I want complete table and using subselect to get average quantity per ordernumber , but as far I know subselect only allows one Column.

And another query where the avg is per Ordernumber and per Prod

```
OrderID|Ordernumber|ProductID|AVGQuantity
1|1234|10|14,7|
2|1234|55|14,7|
3|1234|55|14,7|
4|1029|99|44|
```

Outcome should be:

```
OrderID|Ordernumber|ProductID|AVGQuantity
1|1234|10|11|
2|1234|55|11|
3|1234|55|22|
4|1029|99|44|
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This answers the original version of the question.

You can use window functions:

```
select t.*,
       avg(quantity) over (partition by ordernumber) as avg_quantity
from t;
```

Comment: thanks! But how to calculate average quantity when average are applied to two columns and not just one. see third table in my post as a wanted outcome please.